# Test the converges of complex sequence :$Z_n=(1+i)^{-n}$ and $Z_n=e^{-n\pi i/2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Test the converges of complex sequence :$Z_n=(1+i)^{-n}$ and $Z_n=e^{-n\pi i/2}$

My try:$Z_n=(1+i)^{-n}=(\frac12-\frac i2)^n$,so diverges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z_n=(1+i)^{-n}$ then 
$$|z_n|=|1+i|^{-n}=2^{-\frac{n}{2}}$$
Therefore $|z_n|\to 0$, so $z_n\to 0$.

For the second sequence, you might find it helpful to note that $e^{-\frac{n\pi i}{2}}=i^{-n}$.

Comment: then 2nd one converges to 0?

Comment: No, it diverges. The sequence is $-i,-1,i,1,-i,-1,i,1,\dots$